# How can I find and replace only if a match forms a whole word?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

My script is:

```
n="y"
while [ "{n}" = "y" ]
if [ $n == "n" ];
then
  break;
fi
echo "n is $n"
do
        read -p "Enter the word to find = " word
        read -p "Enter word to replace = " replace
        echo "$word n $replace"
        #sed -i r.text.bak 's/$word/$replace/g' r.txt
        sed -i "s/$word/$replace/g" "test.txt"
echo "do you have further replacement? n or y"
read temp
n=$temp
done
```

My problem is that I am also replacing partial matches. For example, for a line like this:

```
1.1.1.14 1.1.1.14567
```

I get this output:

```
1.1.1.3  1.1.1.3567
```

but I expected:

```
1.1.1.3 1.1.1.14567
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the second line `"{n}" = "y"` or `"${n}" = "y"`?

Comment: Just add `\b` (word limit) to pattern `sed -i "s/$word\b/$replace/g"`

Comment: ohh great. it's worked well.

Comment: sed -i "s/\(^\| \)$word\( \|$\)/\\1$replace\1/g" "test.txt" and i tried with this. its also worked. thanks a lot hatter for quick solution from you. it is the easiest way.

Comment: @Costas please [don't answer questions in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251/203101), that way the question will never be marked as answered and will just stay there.

Comment: Note that it's `s/regex/replacement/`, it's not `s/string/replacement/`. For instance `1.1.1.3` matches `1.1.1.3` but also `1.1.123` (as `.` matches any character).

Answer (score 7):

You need to write your regular expression in a way that only matches whole words. With GNU `sed`, you can use `\b` which matches at word boundaries:

```
sed -i "s/\b$word\b/$replace/g"
```

If you know there will always be a space there, you could just add a space:

```
sed -i "s/ $word /$replace/g"
```

Now, there are also some issues with your script. Your `if ... break` statement is useless, the `while` is already taking care of that. All you need is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
n="y"
while [ "$n" = "y" ]
do
    echo "n is $n"
    read -p "Enter the word to find = " word
    read -p "Enter word to replace = " replace
    echo "$word n $replace"
    sed -i "s/\b$word\b/$replace/g" test.txt
    echo "do you have further replacement? n or y"
    read temp
    n="$temp"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line in the script

```
sed -i "s/$word/$replace/g" "test.txt"
```

with

```
sed -i "s/$\bword\b/$replace/g" test.txt
```

Please refer following link.
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'd use `perl`.

```
WORD=$word REPLACE=$replace perl -pi -e '
  s/\b\Q$ENV{WORD}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE}/g' file
```

`sed` (even GNU `sed`) has no equivalent for `\Q\E` which you need here for the `$word` not to be taken as a regexp. And most `sed` implementations don't support `-i` (or they support it with different syntax) or `\b`.

`\b` matches a transition between a *word* and *non-word* character.

So `\b\Q1.1.2.3\E\b` would still match in `1.1.2.3.4` as `.` is a *non-word*.

You could also do:

```
WORD=$word REPLACE=$replace perl -pi -e '
  s/(?<!\S)\Q$ENV{WORD}\E(?!\S)/$ENV{REPLACE}/g' file
```

To match on `$word` as long as it's not preceded nor followed by a non-spacing character. (using `(?<!)` and `(?!)` negative look behind/forward operators).

Note that `perl` will by default work with ASCII characters. For instance, a *word* character would only be `_a-zA-Z0-9` (`\b\Q1.2.3\E\b` would match in `1.2.3é` and `\S` would match individual bytes of an extended unicode spacing characters). For non-ASCII data, you'd probably want to add the `-CLSD` option to `perl`.

Some examples:

```
$ export WORD=1.1.1.3 REPLACE=REPLACE
$ printf '1.1.1.3-x 1.1.1.3\u2006 1.1.1.3.4 1.1.123 1.1.1.3\u20dd 1.1.1.3\ue9\n' > f
$ cat f
1.1.1.3-x 1.1.1.3  1.1.1.3.4 1.1.123 1.1.1.3⃝ 1.1.1.3é
$ perl -pe 's/\b\Q$ENV{WORD}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE}/g' f
REPLACE-x REPLACE  REPLACE.4 1.1.123 REPLACE⃝ REPLACEé
$ perl -CLSD -pe 's/\b\Q$ENV{WORD}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE}/g' f
REPLACE-x REPLACE  REPLACE.4 1.1.123 1.1.1.3⃝ 1.1.1.3é
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\S)\Q$ENV{WORD}\E(?!\S)/$ENV{REPLACE}/g' f
1.1.1.3-x 1.1.1.3  1.1.1.3.4 1.1.123 1.1.1.3⃝ 1.1.1.3é
$ perl -CLSD -pe 's/(?<!\S)\Q$ENV{WORD}\E(?!\S)/$ENV{REPLACE}/g' f
1.1.1.3-x REPLACE  1.1.1.3.4 1.1.123 1.1.1.3⃝ 1.1.1.3é

$ sed "s/\b$WORD\b/$REPLACE/g" f
REPLACE-x REPLACE  REPLACE.4 REPLACE REPLACE⃝ 1.1.1.3é
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sed -i "s/\s$word\s/$replace/g" "test.txt"
```

sed also support metacharacter `\s`

example

```
var=world

echo "hello world"|sed -r "s/\s$var(\s|$)/.../g"
```

results

```
hello...
```

Note is it is necessary to put `(\s|$)` pattern since a line can end with a word followed by an end of line character instead of  a space